# Table - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui table. I can map the items and display it already however, mapping the orders.items in the table will cause this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

These are the codes:

```
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);


 {orders.map((order) => (
            <div key={order.id}>
              <Typography variant="h6">Ship By:{order.id}</Typography>
              <TableContainer>
                <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="spanning table">
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell align="center" colSpan={3}>
                        Details
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Price</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>Desc</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Qty.</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Unit</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Sum</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <div>
                   <-------------------This is where the error is----------->
                    <TableBody>
                      {orders &&
                        orders.items.map((item) => (
                          <TableRow key={item.documentID}>
                            <TableCell>{item.productName}</TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                   <-------------------This is where the error is----------->
                  </div>
                </Table>
              </TableContainer>
            </div>
```

this is the JSON object

```
[
  {
    id: "IYQss7JM8LS4lXHV6twn",
    total: 130,
    items: [
      {
        qty: 1,
        productPrice: "130",
        documentID: "y8PN1cUyIr1sBnyV3Iqj",
        productName: "Item1",
      },
    ],
    displayName: "Jennie Jenn",
  },
];
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Could you please give us the `orders` json data?

Comment: @AndyRay I've edited the post and showed where the error part is

Comment: can you please share how you are defining `order` in your component?

Comment: @KaustubhKhare edited it already

Comment: @PriyankKachhela I've edited the code, The orders is in array

Comment: Try changing `{orders.map((order) => (` to `{orders && orders.map((order) => (`

Comment: Is the `orders` in the error sections supposed to be plural? Or should it be `order`?

Comment: @Kyruski oh, it was an error. it was supposed to be "order". Thank youu

Answer (score 1):

So at your first render, you will not have `items` in orders array because it is blank array so when it try to map on `order.items` it will give error.

To solve this try to use optional chaining like below:-

```
<TableBody>
  {order &&
    order.items?.map((item) => (
      <TableRow key={item.documentID}>
        <TableCell>{item.productName}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```